# vue Store will not loaded when I create component instances into an array / Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Let me try to explain the circumstances:

I want to create the viewport depending HTML/DOM structure. That means if the user use a landscape viewport he will see an 2 column layout and if he use portrait, then he will see a 1 column layout.

Furthermore it is possible to change the order of the components on the fly.

My Idea is to put each component instance into an object; to acces them by accessing the key and after that building the DOM.

If I do so, the console told me that he cannot read the store within the imported component.

I will try to explain it with some code snippets as well:

```
import MyComponentOne from "@/components/MyComponentOne.vue"
import MyComponentTwo from "@/components/MyComponentTwo.vue"
```

Then I create instances from each component into an object:

```
data()
{
   return 
   {
       instances: {}
   }
},
methods:
{
   createInstances()
   {
       this.instances["MyComponentOne"] = new (Vue.extend(MyComponentOne))();
       this.instances["MyComponentTwo"] = new (Vue.extend(MyComponentTwo))();
   },
   tryToPutItToContent()
   {
       Object.keys(this.instances).forEach(name =>
       {
           this.instances[name].$mount();
           document.getElementById("PlaceToBe").appendChild(this.instances[name].$el);
       });
   }
}
```

This seems to work. But if I use a store (mapStore) within the regarding component, then I will get the property error.

The structure of the sub-components is:

```
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default
    {
        name: "MyComponent",
        data()
        {
            return {
                
            }
        },

        computed:
        {
            ...mapState("labelStore",
                {
                    label: state => state.label
                }),
        }
```

It seems that it is not possible to accessing the store by mapState.

If I just implement the same component into the template area by the standard  it works properly.

The challange of the efforts is, that I can move the components by changing the order or position; also one or two columns, without rerendering the components.

That means if there is an video within an components, it must be feasible to move the component into an other column without stoping or disturbing the playing.

Maybe there is another solution, please let me know.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Sounds over engineered for just a need of changing the layout 

Answer (score 0):

After sleeping a litle bit, I saw it.

I've just added the store by importing it:

```
import store from "@/store/store.js";
```

And than, I've simply added the store to the new vue instance:

```
createInstances()
   {
       this.instances["MyComponentOne"] = new (Vue.extend(MyComponentOne))({ store });
       this.instances["MyComponentTwo"] = new (Vue.extend(MyComponentTwo))({ store });
   },
```

And now it works properly!